# Magento 2 - Filter collection for a multiselect custom product attribute

Tags: php, magento2

I'm fairly new to Magento 2 and I have a custom module which uses a plugin to alter its product collection in the catalog model layer. I created a multiselect custom attribute for the product with the option:

```
backend => '\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend'
```

It successfully creates, populates and saves the multiselect field and its' data from the edit product form. I'm also able to grab all of the values from the multiselect array without a problem:

```
$product->getAllAttributeValues('my_custom_attribute');
```

This prints out something like:

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1,3,4
    )

    [14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

    [32] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3,8
    )
)
```

**So here's my problem:**

Let's say I have a variable

```
$value = "3"
```

and I only want to display products which have that $value in my_custom_attribute. In the example above, only [18] and [32] would be displayed.

Is there a way to do this in Magento 2 with the addAttributeToFilter() method?

For example:

```
$product->addAttributeToFilter('my_custom_attribute', $value);
```

**EDIT:**
Is there a way to do a "nin" (not in) on the array as well so that if $value = 1, only [14] and [32] would be displayed? Eg:

```
$value = 1;
$product->addAttributeToFilter('my_custom_attribute', array('nin' => $value))
```

Comment: here is a list of filters https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html
perhaps you wanted "finset" and "nfinset"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: The purpose of this question was to find out if there was a new Magento 2 way of doing this, but after several days of searching and with the lack of responses, I have come up empty handed. So this answer is based on my experience with Magento 1.x. It works in Magento 2, but there may be a more appropriate way of doing this.

Here's my solution:

```
/**
 * @param $product
 * @return mixed
 */
public function filterProducts($product) {
    $attributeValues = $product->getAllAttributeValues('my_custom_attribute');

    foreach($attributeValues as $entity_id => $value) {
        if($this->_isItemHidden($value[0])) {
            $this->_removeCollectionItems($product, $entity_id);
        }
    }

    return $product;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
protected function _getCustomValue() {
    return '3';
}

/**
 * @param $string
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isItemHidden($string) {

    $customValue= $this->_getCustomValue();

    $multiselectArray= explode(',', $string);

    foreach($multiselectArray as $value) {
        if($value== $customValue){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @param $collection
 * @param $customValue
 */
protected function _removeCollectionItems($collection, $entity_id)
{
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $entity_id));
}
```

Where $this->_getCustomValue() == whatever value you are trying to include or exclude.

So from my plugin, filterProducts() is called passing in the return value from the original function.